# why a jQuery library is not recognized in Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, slick.js

I'm trying to integrate [slick-carousel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/slick-carousel) in my angular app (unfortunately the angular wrapper is very limited and cannot support our cards/slides design).

JQuery is supported in the app (i.e. writing $(#myId).text('text') will change the corresponding DOM element) but cannot figure out why it doesn't recognize slick.

These are the steps I've follwed after `npm install slick-carousel`

in `angular.json` added 'scripts'

```
...
"projects": {
  "my-app": {
    ...
    "architect": {
      "build": {
        ...
        "options": {
          ...
          "scripts": [
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick.min.js"
          ]
        },
        ...
      }...
    }...
  }...
}...
```

and my `component.ts`

```
import * as $ from "jquery";
...
private initSlick(elementId) {
        $('#' + elementId).slick({
            infinite: true,
            slidesToShow: 3,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            draggable: false    
        });
    }
```

this result in error

> Property 'slick' does not exist on type 'JQuery'. Did you
> mean 'click'?

> ```
> 184         $('#' + elementId).slick({
>   node_modules/@types/jquery/JQuery.d.ts:1868:5
>     1868     click<TData>(eventData: TData,
>     1869     handler: JQuery.TypeEventHandler<TElement, TData, TElement, TElement, 'click'>): this;
>     'click' is declared here.
> ```

I've also tried:

- hard coded id just to make sure `$('#myCarousel').slick({`
- entering in html

  ```
     <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
  ```

**UPDATE**
As suggested I've added `<any>` before the JQuery call now the project is compiling successfully **but** I get a runtime error
updated syntax

```
import * as $ from "jquery";
    ...
    private initSlick(elementId) {
       (<any>$('#' + elementId)).slick({
                infinite: true,
                slidesToShow: 3,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
                draggable: false    
            });
        }
```

and the runtime error: `query__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__(...).slick is not a function`

Please help with:

1. Advice on solving the problem
   OR
2. link to tutorial on creating a slide effect in order to try and implement the slide myself

Cheers.

Comment: You can create a custom slider natively. Check this out https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/angular-animations-lets-create-a-carousel-with-reusable-animations-81c0dd8847e8

Comment: @CodeWarrior I'm looking for slide effect like the one in slick

Comment: In that case look at https://swiperjs.com/demos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simpler approach:

Include jQuery script link in index.html. Something like below

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

In your .ts file, declare variable $ like below, outside of class definition. Can be below the last import statement

```
declare var $: any;
```

You can now use jquery selector in angular code without issues.

```
$('#myCarousel').slick({ ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try installing any @types related to slick-carousel, so that Angular could know and detect the types associated with the package.

Comment: changed my code to `(<any>$('#' + elementId)).slick({...` 

now it's not a compiler error but runtime - >query__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__(...).slick is not a function

any ideas?